# How to make yarn start work inside Docker image with react-scripts 3.4 and babel-loader 8.1?

Tags: docker, webpack, yarnpkg, babel-loader, react-scripts

I'm building a Docker image for debugging of my React application with a separate `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:11-alpine

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install

COPY public/ ./public/
COPY src/ ./src/

EXPOSE 3000
CMD yarn run start
```

with `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "yarn-start-in-kubernetes",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

which starts the development server as expected when the image is used with `docker run`. An upgrade to

```
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4"
```

causes the setup to be no longer usable because the development server terminates:

```
> docker run dev
yarn run v1.15.2
$ react-scripts start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Done in 2.72s.
```

The `docker run` returns after `Done in ...`.

I'd like to use the more up-to-date versions which work fine in production. How can I make them work in the debugging image?

The versions don't seem to affect the functioning of the development server outside Docker, i.e. `yarn start` works with both version combinations.

Comment: I posted an answer on a related issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402717/how-to-build-react-app-using-dockerfile-dev/62404976#62404976 It might not answer to your issue because i think you already tried it but who knows ?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and just added:
`stdin_open: true`
to my docker-compose.yml

Comment: Any idea why is this required?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `stdin_open: true` or `tty: true` to the docker-compose file works:

```
services:
  app:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true # without this node doesn't start
```

`stdin_open` stands for standard input (interactive) and `tty` means terminal.

[7e6d6cd](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/7e6d6cd05f3054723c8b015c813e13761659759e) Indicates a check for interactivity.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

If you are not using docker-compose you must use -it together in order to allocate a tty for the container process.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground