# How to build react app using Dockerfile.dev and Yarn

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am trying to run a react app using docker. Here are my steps:

I have created a react app using `react-native-cli` and added `Dockerfile.dev` file. My Dockerfile.dev file contains this code:

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

# Install some depenendencies
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

# Uses port which is used by the actual application
EXPOSE 3000

# Default command
CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

Then I execute this command and get this output. But it doesn't show any port to access it.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .
```

OP: Successfully built ad79cd63eba3

```
docker run ad79cd63eba3
```

OP:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Done in 2.02s.
```

Can anybody tell me how I start the development server and it shows me the port like `Http://localhost:3000` to access it.

Full code: https://github.com/arif2009/frontend.git

Comment: do you need to add `EXPOSE 3000` or whatever your port is, to the dockerfile?

Comment: `docker run -p 3000:3000 yourImage` => https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: @RedBaron I also did it, but it stays same, my full code is here https://github.com/arif2009/frontend.git

Comment: @Zeitounator I understand what you said. But it doesn't shoe any port, so it will not work if I map port with docker.

Comment: Not understanding anything, some bad people are always ready to put done vote.

Comment: Are you trying to run Reactjs or React Native app ? Can you show us your package.json file with the section "Scripts" especially the "start" scripts command

Comment: I am trying to run Reactjs

Comment: okay great : whats append when you just run your app (out of Docker) ? When you just run "yarn run start" from your root folder

Comment: @yAzou I works fine. If you want you can have a look from here https://github.com/arif2009/frontend.git . I think everything is OK. But something need to change my  Dockerfile.dev

Comment: Your Dockerfile is okay. Did you try to `docker run -p 3000:3000 <IMAGE>` (even if it does not show you the port in stdout) and go to `localhost:3000` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it but now working. This is the output https://i.imgur.com/4B43wJv.png

Comment: You misunderstood me : what is the output in the browser ? or if you `curl` to "http://localhost:3000` ? (**not** the output of the `docker run` command....for some reasons it does not show the port but this does not mean that it is not exposed...so just try to navigate to localhost:3000)

Comment: Ok. But browser says "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Okay. Something weird append here.  Can you try to add a port property on the start command in your package.json like so : `"scripts": {
    "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start"}` and expose the 3001 in your dockerfile ? Tell me if it changes something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216036/discussion-between-arif-and-yazou).

Comment: docker run is ok,but docker-compose up get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with Docker and the last version of react scripts. 
Here is a Github thread about it : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

The (temporary and fastest) solution for your case is to downgrade the version of react-scripts in your package.json file. 
From :

```
    "dependencies": {
     ...
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
    }
```

To :

```
   "dependencies": {
     ...
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
    }
```

I tested your project with this configuration and it works well now.

From the above Github Thread it seems to be another solution with docker-compose and `stdin_open: true` option (which basically correspond to the `-it` flag of the `docker run` command. You can try that too if the react-scripts version matter for you (and you want to keep the last version of it)

Comment: About your second section of answer, the complete command I used to work is `docker run -it -p LocalPort:DockerPort ImageId`

Answer (score 3):

This is for docker yarn react

```
# pull the base image
FROM node:lts-alpine

# set the working direction
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./

COPY yarn.lock ./

# rebuild node-sass
RUN yarn add node-sass

RUN yarn

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:14.5.0 as build-deps

# Create working directory and copy the app before running yarn install as the artifactory
# credentials can be inside .npmrc
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . ./

# Run yarn install
RUN yarn install

# Build the project
CMD ["yarn", "run", "build"]

# Install serve command for yarn package manager
RUN yarn global add serve

# Navigate to build folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/build

# Start the application
CMD serve -p 80 -s .
```

Comment: I'm still testing, but I think this Dockerfile will work for me.